# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup ''_WL_internal_..." didn't find subcontext '_WL_internal_ . Resolved ''; remaining

Tags: java, jms, weblogic

I've developed a EJB application, with a Remote interface. This application was deployed on WebLogic 12.

With a Java application, I'm trying to deploy or start application I am getting this Exception:

I think it is happening because of JMS configuration, but I have but I have also configured complete JMS from scratch, but I'm still getting this Exception.

```
<Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "1141789489700" for task "1" on [partition-name: DOMAIN]. Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup '_WL_internal_YDiu1y8UO4ks7gvaXeAiteRhQj8wZsZhk0yi3L7HfRtK6vSG2Zu8H2Dqppd3YjTt.global' didn't find subcontext '_WL_internal_YDiu1y8UO4ks7gvaXeAiteRhQj8wZsZhk0yi3L7HfRtK6vSG2Zu8H2Dqppd3YjTt'. Resolved ''; remaining name '_WL_internal_YDiu1y8UO4ks7gvaXeAiteRhQj8wZsZhk0yi3L7HfRtK6vSG2Zu8H2Dqppd3YjTt/global'" weblogic.application.ModuleException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup '_WL_internal_YDiu1y8UO4ks7gvaXeAiteRhQj8wZsZhk0yi3L7HfRtK6vSG2Zu8H2Dqppd3YjTt.global' didn't find subcontext '_WL_internal_YDiu1y8UO4ks7gvaXeAiteRhQj8wZsZhk0yi3L7HfRtK6vSG2Zu8H2Dqppd3YjTt'. Resolved ''; remaining name '_WL_internal_YDiu1y8UO4ks7gvaXeAiteRhQj8wZsZhk0yi3L7HfRtK6vSG2Zu8H2Dqppd3YjTt/global'
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:114)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextStateInParallel(StateMachineDriver.java:144)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.parallelPrepare(ModuleStateDriver.java:46)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:75)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:55)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:241)
        at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.prepare(SingleModuleDeployment.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:65)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.RedeployOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(RedeployOperation.java:104)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.RedeployOperation.doPrepare(RedeployOperation.java:139)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:242)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:800)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1352)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:270)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:177)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:186)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:47)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:670)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
        at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
        at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)
Caused By: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: While trying to lookup '_WL_internal_YDiu1y8UO4ks7gvaXeAiteRhQj8wZsZhk0yi3L7HfRtK6vSG2Zu8H2Dqppd3YjTt.global' didn't find subcontext '_WL_internal_YDiu1y8UO4ks7gvaXeAiteRhQj8wZsZhk0yi3L7HfRtK6vSG2Zu8H2Dqppd3YjTt'. Resolved ''; remaining name '_WL_internal_YDiu1y8UO4ks7gvaXeAiteRhQj8wZsZhk0yi3L7HfRtK6vSG2Zu8H2Dqppd3YjTt/global'
        at weblogic.rjvm.ResponseImpl.unmarshalReturn(ResponseImpl.java:309)
        at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:555)
        at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:313)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.ServerNamingNode_12213_WLStub.lookup(Unknown Source)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:449)
        at weblogic.jndi.internal.WLContextImpl.lookup(WLContextImpl.java:435)
        at weblogic.application.naming.EnvironmentBuilder.initGlobalNodes(EnvironmentBuilder.java:285)
        at weblogic.application.naming.EnvironmentBuilder.<init>(EnvironmentBuilder.java:252)
        at weblogic.application.naming.BindingsFactory.createWebAppEnvironment(BindingsFactory.java:35)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.CompEnv.<init>(CompEnv.java:102)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.<init>(WebAppServletContext.java:379)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.HttpServer.loadWebApp(HttpServer.java:648)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.registerWebApp(WebAppModule.java:1420)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:810)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$PrepareStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:295)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$PrepareStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:285)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:109)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextStateInParallel(StateMachineDriver.java:144)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.parallelPrepare(ModuleStateDriver.java:46)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:75)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:55)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:241)
        at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.prepare(SingleModuleDeployment.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:65)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.RedeployOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(RedeployOperation.java:104)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.RedeployOperation.doPrepare(RedeployOperation.java:139)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:242)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:800)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1352)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:270)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:177)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:186)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14)
        at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:47)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:670)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
        at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
        at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)
```

Comment: Chexk if there is no profile issue in your application, as different profiles will have different configurations that's why app is not getting started when wrong conf is met with WebLogic.